# How to increase size of circle of home button in persistent navigation bar

Tags: flutter

```
child: Center(
                    child: Container(
                      width: 250.0,
                      //height: height,
                      height: 200,
                      margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 2.0),
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        shape: BoxShape.circle,
                        color: Colors.white,
                        border: Border.all(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            width: 6.0,
                             boxShadow: this.navBarDecoration!.boxShadow,
                      ),
```

[image: outPut]

Comment: can you include full widget of `persistent navigation bar`

Comment: give radius property in BoxDecoration => borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),